# Echoing data from msql database to textarea in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can't figure out how to echo data stored in my mysql database into textareas in HTML. It works fine with normal text boxes, as I know text boxes take a "value" but textareas don't, but when I try to echo the data it comes up blank every time.

Here is my code for the textarea:

```
<tr>
     <td><label for="exampleInputName2">Caractéristiques</br>de l'écrit: </label></td>
     <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="caractéristiques" <?php echo "$donnees[caracs]";?>></textarea></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

Whereas this works fine with text boxes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" name="periode" value="<?php echo "$donnees[periode]"?>">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write your code `<textarea>Your text</textarea>` and remove quotes from echo as its variable.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
         <td><label for="exampleInputName2">Caractéristiques</br>de l'écrit: </label></td>
         <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="caractéristiques">Here your textarea text comes<?php echo $donnees['caracs'];?></textarea></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry? I didn't realise you couldn't accept 2 answers. I wanted to accept them both as they're the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
 <tr>
  <td><labelfor="exampleInputName2">Caractéristiques
      </br>del'écrit</label></td>
  <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="caractéristiques" 
   ><?php echo $donnees['caracs'];?></textarea></td>
</tr>
```